# Static files not being served by nginx

Tags: nginx

In **bold** the solution.

Solution:
Changed this nginx line to:

```
        location /cm/static {
                alias /var/www/KRAKEN/public/cm/static;
        }
```

i hope this is a quickie. This is my app structure:

```
/var/www/KRAKEN/public/cm/
.
|-- __init__.py
|-- __pycache__
|-- bin
|-- include
|-- lib
|-- mod_db
|-- mod_form
|-- requirements.txt
|-- static
|-- templates
|-- uwsgi.ini
|-- uwsgi.log
|-- views.py
```

For some reason, NGINX is throwing me 404 when accessing the static files (in my Flask app they are not used even though the path is correct). Here is the nginx config:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name server.me www.server.me;
        root /var/www/KRAKEN/public/;
        error_log /var/www/KRAKEN/public/nginx.error.log;
        location / {
           index index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        location /cm {
                include uwsgi_params;
                uwsgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /cm;
                uwsgi_pass unix:///var/www/KRAKEN/public/cm/socket.sock;
        }

        location /static {
                alias /var/www/KRAKEN/public/cm/static;
        }
}
```

request header example of one of the 404 files:

```
GET /cm/static/style.css HTTP/1.1
Host: www.server.me
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Accept: text/css,*/*;q=0.1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36
Referer: http://www.server.me/cm/
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es-419;q=0.6,es;q=0.4
```

response example:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND
Server: nginx/1.8.1
Date: Tue, 15 Mar 2016 18:20:35 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 233
Connection: keep-alive
```

The error log shows nothing.

What am i missing?

Thanks!

Comment: The error log will give you the clue you need.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks Mike, but the log shows nothing.

Comment: If you're not logging 404 (or other messages) then you need to fix that first and then present us with the data. Right now there is nothing in your question that is of any use to us.

Comment: Can you post an exact request with headers? Your alias seems to suggest Nginx never serves anything from the /static folder. If it's the contents of that folder you mean yield 404s, your alias is probably the cause.

Comment: @JayMcTee done! check it out.

Comment: Note that your solution is a bit strange. An alias is meant to point to some place else, not to itself. You may as well remove it, for clarity.

Comment: @JayMcTee for some reason, if i remove the /static, the assets wont load.

Answer (score 2):

There is no style.css in /var/www/KRAKEN/public/cm/ hence a 404.

> What am i missing?

You are missing style.css in the cm folder.

Reconsider the alias for the static location, as this seems to be confusing you.